# Python: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file called *differences.txt* and put it into a one line variable.

Here is *differences.txt*:

```
192.168.0.***
192.168.0.***
```

and my code:

```
with open ("/home/pi/Documents/difference.txt") as myfile:
    difip=myfile.readlines()
    print (difip)
```

and my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/clean.py", line 95, in <module>
body = "Different IP's:" + difip
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Any help will be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Then just convert it explicitly. How exactly are you going to convert it? There are more than one ways and they get different results.

Comment: If you want to read it as one big string, with `\n` newline characters in it, instead of a list of strings, one for each line, just `myfile.read()`, not `myfile.readlines()`.

Comment: But it would really help if you showed us what your intended output is, instead of making us guess.

Comment: @l'L'l I don't think it's a dup of that question. That one is about whether/why you should use the new `with` feature in Python 2.4…

Comment: @abarnert: Gotcha, this question is unclear tbh. cheers! :)

Comment: Thank you @abarnert **so much** it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

```
myfile.readlines()
```

returns a list of lines of the file 
(remember, this includes \n for new lines). In your case it's returning

```
    ["192.168.0.***\n", "192.168.0.***\n"]
```

Optn 1) You should be using the strip() function instead

```
myfile = open('/home/pi/Documents/difference.txt', 'r')
text = myfile.read().strip() #pass ("\n") as argument to strip() to remove the newlines.
```

Optn 2) Optionally you can use your same code but modify the last line as follows:

```
with open ("/home/pi/Documents/difference.txt") as myfile:
    difip=myfile.readlines()
print (difip[0] + difip[1])
```

This error message

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

is telling you that you are trying to print the list as a string. What this last change makes is print the strings that are stored in the first two lines of the text file.

Comment: The print function isn't where the error is occurring, print can deal with any object as input.  It isn't clear unless you look at the actual stack trace provided, but the problem occurs when the list is concatenated to a string elsewhere in the code.

Also you don't need to explicitly close a file with a using statement, that's what the using statement is for.